# Flash AS3 EventDispatcher - any way of getting a list of registered listeners?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, event-handling, listeners

Is there any way of getting a list of registered listeners for an `EventDispatcher`?

I know that `EventDispatcher` has the `hasEventListener` method to tell you if any listeners are registered, but is there an easy way of interrogating the `EventDispatcher` to find out what the listeners are?

One way I figured to do this was to subclass `EventDispatcher` to override the `addEventListener` method and store the listeners in a dictionary, but this feels clunky to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: have been longing for something likely as well but the solution you mentioned seems to be the be the only one so far ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that there is no answer to this question other than my original idea of storing listeners in a Dictionary and removing them explicitly. Oh well...

Some interesting thoughts about the [intricacies AS3 Events system can be found here](http://robertpenner.com/flashblog/2009/09/as3-events-7-things-ive-learned-from.html).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is a complete solution but it might help you on your way:

http://www.rialvalue.com/blog/2009/09/08/does-an-eventdispatcher-have-subscribed-listeners/

From the article:

> The example above shows how we can get
>   a reference to the different listeners
>   declared in an EventDispatcher and how
>   to remove them without having a direct
>   reference (and knowing the event name
>   arggg).
>
> Even though this can help you to
>   figure out if an EventDispatcher has
>   listeners or not there’re still
>   several problems you might find:
>
> ```
> * You don’t have any information about the listener
> * You don’t know which event the listener is listening to
> * We don’t know which phase the listener is listening to
> * Haven’t done too much testing around this, but I think both weak and strong references are hold in the list
> * The other thing to consider is that flash.sampler.getMemberNames only works in the debugger version of the Flash Player
> ```

Comment: That was helpful, but it doesn't really solve my problem - if it only works in the debugger version of the player I can't use it for any real-world applications...