# How to remove a event listener with an unknown function in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

My idea in a small upload software is to use always the same object for all tasks (defined before), I just add and remove the events and make the requests, since the parameters are always the same (same method, same url...).

Any time the request is completed, I remove the listeners so the same object can be used again.

The problem is when some error occurs, than the listener call the the function ioerror, but I don't know what function should be called instead if there was no error:

```
private function ioerror(e:IOErrorEvent){
                e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, unknownfuncion);
                e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerror);
                msg("Error somewhere ("+e.text+")");
            }
```

How to get the name of "unknownfunction" ? My fear is to leave events behind...

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a couple of simple classes to manage a collection of event listeners. Lets call the collection `EventBatch`, which could look like this:

```
public class EventBatch
{

    private var _items:Vector.<EventBatchItem> = new <EventBatchItem>[];


    public function addListener(target:IEventDispatcher, type:String, callback:Function):void
    {
        var item:EventBatchItem = new EventBatchItem(target, type, callback);
        _items.push(item);

        target.addEventListener(type, callback);
    }


    public function removeAll():void
    {
        for each(var i:EventBatchItem in _items)
        {
            i.target.removeEventListener(i.type, i.callback);
            i.dispose();
        }

        _items = new <EventBatchItem>[];
    }

}
```

And here's the accompanying model to represent an item:

```
internal class EventBatchItem
{

    private var _target:IEventDispatcher;
    private var _type:String;
    private var _callback:Function;


    public function EventBatchItem(target:IEventDispatcher, type:String, callback:Function)
    {
        _target = target;
        _type = type;
        _callback = callback;
    }


    internal function dispose():void
    {
        _target = null;
        _callback = null;
    }


    internal function get target():IEventDispatcher{ return _target; }
    internal function get type():String{ return _type; }
    internal function get callback():Function{ return _callback; }

}
```

This way, you can add your event listeners like this:

```
var batch:EventBatch = new EventBatch();
batch.addListener(urlLoader, Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
batch.addListener(urlLoader, SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
batch.addListener(urlLoader, IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

And in any of those listener functions, simply use the `.removeAll()` method:

```
batch.removeAll();
```

Comment: It's a fine solution, but still a "bureaucratic" solution. It seams there is no solution as I would like... Thanks, I'll keep this at hand! In my case, I'm also thinking about using not only the same object, but a entire class, so the problem may be "encapsulated" instead of fragmented all over the code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the handler is reset and an instance to the object is retained, you could simply set `useWeakReference` to true in your [`addEventListener()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) function for garbage collection.

However, a better design pattern is to abstract service methods to a class.

Then, calling `dispose` can remove all handlers.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

    public class AbstractService extends EventDispatcher
    {

        public var data:Object;

        public var requestMethod:String = URLRequestMethod.GET;

        public var url:String;

        protected var urlLoader:URLLoader;

        protected var urlRequest:URLRequest;

        public function AbstractService()
        {
            super();

            urlLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param url
         * @param data String or URLVariables
         */
        public function load(url:String=null, data:Object=null, requestMethod:String=URLRequestMethod.GET):void
        {
            if (url)
                this.url = url;

            if (data)
                this.data = data;

            if (requestMethod)
                this.requestMethod = requestMethod;

            urlRequest = new URLRequest(this.url);
            urlRequest.data = this.data;
            urlRequest.method = this.requestMethod;

            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
        }

        protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
        }

        protected function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
        }

        protected function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
        {
        }

        public function dispose():void
        {
            urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            urlLoader.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            urlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work at all. The asker doesn't need to know what is calling the event, they needs to know what function is currently tied to a completely separate event listener so they can remove that specific listener

Comment: As a followup, my comment was made before an edit when `arguments.callee` was suggested. Obviously, my comment no longer applies. The current answer is fairly effective, though it is no different than what was provided by Aralicia (save for abstracting it into a separate method, which would be the correct way to handle this situation)

Answer (score 1):

If you known all the functions that could possibly be added as a Listener, you can just remove all of them. Using removeEventListener() with a method that is not actually listening do nothing. So you could use something like that :

```
private function ioerror(e:IOErrorEvent){
  // I know that Event.COMPLETE could be listened by function1, function2 or function3
  // I remove all of them
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function1);
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function2);
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function3);
  e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerror);
  msg("Error somewhere ("+e.text+")");
}
```

Another possibility is to keep track of the method(s) actually listening the event in a variable.

```
public function doSomething() {
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteSomething);
  listeningComplete= onCompleteSomething;
}
public function doSomethingElse() {
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteSomethingElse);
  listeningComplete= onCompleteSomethingElse;
}

private function ioerror(e:IOErrorEvent){
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, listeningComplete);
  e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerror);
  msg("Error somewhere ("+e.text+")");
}

private var listeningComplete:Function;
```

Comment: So it seams there is no way to discover that function, uhn... Well, this what we got now, but would be fine some method like "removeAllEventListeners(type)" or a simple "shutUp()"...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my previous answer to [Is There A Way To Remove Events Easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881289/is-there-a-way-to-remove-listeners-easier/14881480#14881480). Basically, there is no easy way to do it. In that answer, I put together a simple way to track events that are added to a class by simply overriding the event listener methods. Using that method, you could just call `removeAllEventListeners()` and be done with it. It works fairly well, so long as you consistently remember to call that function (otherwise things will never get removed from memory).

This is overkill for the majority of situations, however. I'm currently using it for a massive application and it has helped immensely, but for something simple, it is just going to add extra computations and memory consumption to your app that is unneeded.

Comment: This seams very useful for big and complex software. In my case, I'll just create a simple function and add all event removers needed. So far, we must always keep track of all listeners in way or another. Thanks.

Comment: @GustavoPinent Yes, as I mentioned, it is very useful when you are creating massive applications where it is not feasible to manually track listeners that may or may not be added. For a smaller application, it is best just to manually track them because you generally know exactly what is being added.

Comment: There are better designs to abstract this type of reuse than this.

Comment: @JasonSturges Such as? I'm still trying to optimize my app, so any improvement on my designs are welcome.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know if I do "re-create" the objects (obj:URLLoader = new URLLoader) will drop the listeners or they will remain inactive...

Comment: @GustavoPinent That does not "recreate" objects. The object still exists and it still has all of its event listeners attached. All that does is "repurpose" the variable/memory reference for accessing a new object. Before you do that, you should remove event listeners on the previous object, else it will not be eligible for GC

Comment: This `Vector.<Object>` collection of loosely typed object literals overriding event dispatcher base functions seems overly dynamic.  Also makes for difficult inheritance.

Comment: @JasonSturges I applied that in my Sprite class replacement and ~90% of the DisplayObjects in my project extend it. There have been no issues at all with inheritance. I do agree that using a `Vector.<Object>` is not specific enough to truly take advantage of Vector speed improvements, but I did some basic testing before implementation and on average was still 10-15% faster than using an array.

Comment: Like [RPC responders](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/Responder.html), or some functionality with `flash.net` package, service classes are nicely abstracted from display list entities.  What you're extending is functionality within `EventDispatcher`, before any `DisplayObject` in the inheritance chain.